# Как прописать After или before в Javascript

Tags: javascript

Как прописать After или before в Javascript ? и возможно ли такое вообще ! заранее спасибо !

Comment: [Добавление и удаление узлов][1] 

[1]: http://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document

Answer (score 1):

Напрямую взаимодействовать нельзя, но можно добавить inline-стили.

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/zjkX4/)**

```
var addRule = (function (style) {
    var sheet = document.head.appendChild(style).sheet;
    return function (selector, css) {
        var propText = "";
        // Если передана строка, оставляем, как есть
        if (typeof css === "string") {
            propText = css;
        } 
        // Если передан объект, обрабатываем каждый ключ
        else {
            propText = Object.keys(css).map(function (property) {
                var value = "";
                // Если попалось свойство "content",
                // заключаем значение в кавычки
                if (property === "content") {
                    value = "'" + css[property] + "'";
                // Иначе оставляем, как есть
                } else {
                    value = css[property];
                }
                // Склеиваем в строку пару "ключ" и "значение"
                return property + ":" + value;
            }).join(";"); // Склеиваем в строку все свойства
        }
        sheet.insertRule(selector + "{" + propText + "}", sheet.cssRules.length);
    };
})(document.createElement("style"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще насколько мне известно - нельзя. Но есть такой костыль, как:
создать класс CSS с псевдоэлементом, и использовать `$('.obj').addClass('class');`

Примерно так: http://jsfiddle.net/Fbe5r/

Другие способы мне неизвестны.